# C++ Using “if else” and variable count for loop iterations need to result in zero balance

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

I am using the “if else” and variable count for loop iterations which needs to result in zero balance. I have written my code for the following problem but, I cannot get the final results. 
Which is the final balance should show a zero balance. I would like to know how to fix it.
Please see problem and code below.
Thank You in Advance.

> PROBLEM You have just purchased a
>   stereo system that costs $2,000 on the
>   following credit plan:  no down
>   payment, an interest rate of 18% per
>   year (and hence 1.5% per month) and
>   monthly payments of $75.
>
> The monthly payment of $75 is used to
>   pay the interest and whatever is left
>   over is used to pay part of the
>   remaining debt. Hence, the first month
>   you pay 1.5% of $2,000 in interest .
>   That’s $30 in interest. So, the
>   remaining $45 is deducted from your
>   debt, which leaves you with a debt of
>   $1955.00. The next month you pay
>   interest of 1.5% of $1955.00, which is
>   $29.32 and you deduct $75 - $29.32
>   which is $45.67 from the amount you
>   owe.
>
> Have your program print out the month,
>   the amount of interest paid, and the
>   amount of the debt that is paid and
>   the debt that remains in a nice table
>   form. Make sure to include a line in
>   the table for the final month that you
>   pay. Your remaining debt should be
>   zero for that line! Be sure to print
>   money out to 2 decimal places, as
>   shown below.

```
Sample output: 
Thank you for purchasing your new stereo system.
The following is your payment plan for the cost of $2000.00
with 1.50% interest and payments of $75.00 a month.

Month   Interest Paid   Debt Paid       Total Payment   Balance
1            30.00              45.00              75.00                 1955.00
2            29.32              45.67              75.00                 1909.33
3            28.64              46.36              75.00                 1862.96
4            27.94              47.06              75.00                 1815.91
5            27.24              47.76              75.00                 1768.15
6            26.52              48.48              75.00                 1719.67
7            25.80              49.20              75.00                 1670.47
8            25.06              49.94              75.00                 1620.52
9            24.31              50.69              75.00                 1569.83
10          23.55              51.45              75.00                 1518.38
11          22.78              52.22              75.00                 1466.15
12          21.99              53.01              75.00                 1413.15
13          21.20              53.80              75.00                 1359.34
14          20.39              54.61              75.00                 1304.73
15          19.57              55.43              75.00                 1249.30
16          18.74              56.26              75.00                 1193.04
17          17.90              57.10              75.00                 1135.94
18          17.04              57.96              75.00                 1077.98
19          16.17              58.83              75.00                 1019.15
20          15.29              59.71              75.00                 959.43
21          14.39              60.61              75.00                 898.83
22          13.48              61.52              75.00                 837.31
23          12.56              62.44              75.00                 774.87
24          11.62              63.38              75.00                 711.49
25          10.67              64.33              75.00                 647.16
26          9.71                65.29              75.00                 581.87
27          8.73                66.27              75.00                 515.60
28          7.73                67.27              75.00                 448.33
29          6.73                68.27              75.00                 380.06
30          5.70                69.30              75.00                 310.76
31          4.66                70.34              75.00                 240.42
32          3.61                71.39              75.00                 169.03
33          2.54                72.46              75.00                 96.56
34          1.45                73.55              75.00                 23.01
35          0.35                23.01              23.36                 0.00
```

Note that the last payment is  $23.36,

Hints: Use a variable to count  the number of loop iterations and hence the number of months until the debt is zero.

Be careful, the last payment may be less than $75. 
Also, don’t forget the interest on the last payment. If you owe $75,then your monthly payment of $75 will not pay it off, but will come close.

Make sure you look carefully at your final output to check that it is correct!

MY CODE

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float balance;
    float interest;
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    double loan, monthlypay, IntRat;
    double e = 0;
    double a, b, c, d;
    double Interestpay;
    double i;

    cout << "Enter the amount of the loan: $";
    cin >> loan;
    cout << "Enter the interst per year:";
    cin >> Interestpay;
    cout << "Enter the monthly pay: $";
    cin >> monthlypay;

    c = loan;

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for ( i=1; c>0; i++)


    {
        IntRat = Interestpay/100/12;

        a = IntRat*c;

        b = monthlypay-a;

        cout << "Month: "<<i<<endl;
        cout << "Principle Interest:" <<a<<endl;
        cout << "Principle Remaining: $" <<b<<endl;

        c = c-b;
        cout << "You still have a balance of: $" <<c<<endl;
        cout << endl;
        d=e+a;
        e=d;

    }

    i=i-1;
    if (c >=b)
           c = c -b;

    else if (c>0.1)
           c=c*1;
           c = 0;


        cout << "Your last payment is " <<  c << endl;

        cout << "\nThe total month is:" <<i<<endl;
        cout << "The total Interest paid is:" <<d<<endl;
        cout << "You have a credit of:" <<c<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please tag homework questions as such.

Answer (score 7):

It is generally not recommended to use floating-point types to represent currency amounts. It's typically better to use "fixed point". A simple way of doing that is to e.g. use an integer type such as `int`, and just scale up.

Instead of doing

```
double monthlyPayment = 75.0;
```

use

```
int montlyPayment = 7500;
```

Then you need to divide by 10<sup>2</sup> if you e.g. multiply two currency amounts together, and so on, but doing it this way can often make the calculations more exact (unless you go out of range, but for this simple example I think you'll be safe).

If you need more precision, scale by a larger amount such as `10000`, but be aware that doing so decreases the range.

Comment: 100^2 = 10000... I'm guessing that you meant to write 10^2.

Comment: Or `100^1`. Obviously it is equal to `10^2`, but if two numbers are represented by their "true values" scaled by N, and you multiply them together, then the value you need to divide by to get the result scaled the same as the inputs is N, not N^2. In fact, multiplying two currency amounts together is almost always wrong - consider the dimensions of the result. But if you've scaled your currency and also scaled your interest rate, then you have a similar issue.

Comment: And as a further related point, from the POV of accountancy software the scale chosen matters. Question says to *print* the values to 2dp, but it doesn't say what precision to use when calculating and compounding interest. OK, so it makes maybe a few pennies difference either way, but that matters to regulatory authorities. When dealing with money you have to know whether you're expected to round to $0.001 or $0.0001, when you have to round (i.e. what intermediate values can/must be more precise), and what direction(s) to round in what contexts.

Comment: +1 for suggesting scaled down integer types as fixed-point decimals instead of floating point variables.

Comment: @Michael: true, typo fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

From a fast look, maybe you mean :

```
i=i-1;
if (c >=b)
{
       c = c -b;
}else if (c>0.1)
{
       c=c*1;
       c = 0;
}
```

In your code `c = 0;` is executed irrespectively of the `if` clause. If that is not the case please fix your code indent.

In case you mean what I post in this answer, you realize that `c` will be `0` ? In the case your code is what you meant, you realize that no matter what `c` will be `0` ?

Comment: `c=c*1; c=0;` surely is unintentional wherever the braces go. (a) why multiply a number by constant 1? (b) why do anything to a number immediately before setting it to 0?